# how to get the json key value pair in specific format

Tags: javascript, json

i have json array like below:

```
var region= [{"af":"Africa"},{"as":"Asia"},{"au":"Australia"}]
```

I am using some framework in that i got value of above array as:

```
{for r in regions}
     <option value="${r}" >${r}</option>
{/for}
```

i tried javascript but didn't succeded. I want the output in above format

plz help me out this.

Comment: So you're using a templating system, and would like to know what's inside the templates so you can get some data from an object ?

Comment: yes i m new to that and want to loop like i asked in question plz help

Comment: i want to get the key as well as value

Comment: `region[0].af` should get you Africa, other than that, I really don't get the question regarding the templates ?

Comment: i want whole array to be printed in select box/dropdown how can i get that is this clear...

Answer (score 1):

```
var region= [{"af":"Africa"},{"as":"Asia"},{"au":"Australia"}],
    len = region.length,
    i, key;

for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    key = Object.keys(region[i])[0];
    console.log(key, region[i][key]);
}​
```

`Object.keys` in this code returns an array of all keys of the object. And as long as you have 1 and only 1 key per object - you just retrieve the first using `[0]`

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/hYFHy/

Comment: sorry but i need output as i stated above coz this is not working in my application

Comment: @user1897933: I've given you an idea how to extract the data, now it's your turn to get exactly what you want. "i need output as i stated above" --- I'm sorry, it's not a volunteers site, we don't do your work for free.